# Grafica en r con 2 variables GGPLOT

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Tengo un dataframe de muertes en r con muchas columnas, pero me interesa graficar la fecha con el genero y cantidad de muertes.

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma de graficar 2 lineas dependiendo del sexo?
Tengo este código

```
grafica2012 <- letal_mexico %>% ggplot(aes(x=FECHA_TOTAL,y=ENT_REGIS))      
+geom_line(aes(y=SEXO==2),color="red")  +geom_line(aes(y=SEXO==1),color="blue") +ylab("Muertes")
+ xlab("Fecha") +theme_ipsum()

grafica2012 <- ggplotly(grafica2012)
grafica2012
```

En las geom_line quiero que uno sea para hombre y otro mujer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En algunos casos dos `geom_line()` independientes puede ser útil, pero en el tuyo, no es necesario. Lo que debes hacer es "mapear" una nueva dimensión estética, el `color` y asociarla al `SEXO`, con esto, el `geom_line()` ya entiende que tiene que dibujar dos líneas:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)

letal_mexico <- data.frame(FECHA_TOTAL = rep(as.Date('2020-01-01') + 1:50,2), 
                           ENT_REGIS = sample(100:300, 100),
                           SEXO = rep(1:2, each=50))

letal_mexico %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=FECHA_TOTAL,y=ENT_REGIS, color=ifelse(SEXO==1, 'Hombres', 'Mujeres'))) +
  geom_line() +
  ylab("Muertes") +
  xlab("Fecha") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

Fijate que "mapeamos" la estética así `color=ifelse(SEXO==1, 'Hombres', 'Mujeres')` para mostrar los textos y no la formula de selección, luego con `scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))` definimos la escal de valores justamente para `color`.

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]